Google Analytics data is visible when running the site locally but not when deployed through Jenkins on Ubuntu
The issue of Google Analytics data not appearing when deployed through Jenkins on Ubuntu, but visible when running locally.
By suggesting these steps, I expected to narrow down the root cause of the issue. The goal was to identify where the difference lies between the local and deployed environments

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
